# Is my understanding of this While Loop correct?

Tags: java

The example in the book asks the user to enter any positive number. Then the program will add the individual digits separately and print the total. For example if the user enters the number 7512 the program is designed to add 7 + 5 + 1 + 2 and then print the total.

I've written out the way I understand how the code works. Is this correct? Is my understanding of this loop correct with each step, or am I missing any calculations? What happens during the 4th loop when there is no remainder in 7 % 10?

```
1st  run of loop ... sum = sum + 7512 % 10 which is equal to 2 
                        n = 7512 / 10 which which equals to 751 

2nd run of loop ... sum = 2 + 751 % 10 which is equal to 1 
                         n = 751 / 10  which is equal to 75 

3rd run of loop ...  sum = 3 + 75 % 10 which is equal to 5 
                          n  = 75 / 10 which is equal to 7

4th run of loop ...  sum = 8 + 7 % 10   <------?
```

---

```
import acm.program.*; 

   public class DigitSum extends ConsoleProgram{

   public void run() {
   println("This program will add the integers in the number you enter.");
   int n = readInt("Enter a positive integer: ");
   int sum = 0;
   while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10; 
    }
    println("The sum of the digits is" + sum + ".");    
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in you debugger and then you will be able to see exactly what each line does at the values at each line.

Comment: Reading answers is believing, singlestepping code is knowing.

Comment: @theBlastOne I didn't know how to do that before but I went back and checked the answers that help me the most. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks I'll definitely do that next time. I just wanted to double check that I had the correct value after every loop run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of the operation `7 % 10` is 7, the remainder when you divide 7 by 10.  The last iteration of the loop is to add 7 to the prior value.  The next division step inside the loop (`n /= 10;`) takes n to 0, which is what ends the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was a little confused about when the loop ended.

Comment: @JessicaM. This exercise illustrates the different purposes between integer division and the modulus (%) operator quite nicely.  You'll see it in a lot of introductory programming books for that reason, so it's a good program to try and get a good understanding of.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is not the same as `/`

The `%` operator is for the modulus, not division... This means that the result of the operations is not dividing, but obtaining the remainder of the division, like:

```
7512 % 10 => 2  
751 % 10 => 1  
75 % 10 => 5  
7 % 10 => 7
```

This kind of logic is fairly frequently used when dealing with numeric operations.

Comment: With a new programmer who doesn't know that, is it wise to assume they're also familiar with `!=` :)?

Comment: @RohitJain I'm a fan of commit early commit often

Comment: @ppeterka Sure, there is nothing wrong in that, but you should commit to the point.

Comment: @Mikaveli as she showed good understanding of the surroundings of the code, I trusted her to know this, but there you go, corrected.

Comment: @ppeterka No worries (PS, I up-voted your answer - I'm not sure why it attracted down votes?).

Comment: @Mikaveli Thanks. I didn't understand that either. Well, somebody just might have a bad day, hope he gets better

Answer (score 0):

- before run, sum = 0, n = 7512
- 1st run of loop ... sum = 0 + 2 => sum = 2, n = 751
- 2nd run of loop ... sum = 2 + 1 => sum = 3, n = 75
- 3rd run of loop ... sum = 3 + 5 => sum = 8, n = 7
- 4th run of loop ... sum = 8 + 7 => sum = 15, n = 0

Comment: thanks for the breakdown it really looks simple when you write it.

Answer (score 0):

After `7%10` you get `7` and that is added to your result. 
And `7/10` will result in `0` and hence your loop ends and your sum now has addition that you want.